# Okta SAML integration in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, saml-2.0, okta

I am new to SAML. We have integrated okta SAML with our spring application for single sign on. The application is working fine on localhost, but when deployed on our server it gives the folllowing exception:
Incoming SAML message is invalid
org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed

I will brief the process i have followed for integration. I have used the configurations from the sample application. I have created my keystore, added the public certificate from okta to the keystore. Now for

```
  <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
```

we need a the private key. For the private key I generated a private key using openssl tool
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
From this certificate and private key I generated a .p12 file and imported it in keystore.
My configuration is

```
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="myPswd"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="myprivateKeyAlias" value="myPswd"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="myprivateKeyAlias"/>
</bean>
```

But still I get the same error when deployed on server. 
I have done some research and found this on some links that it most likely means that the public key (part of the certificate in the SAML MetaData ... KeyInfo "signing" Element) does not "match" the private key used to sign the message. I am not sure how to resolve this exception.

Comment: To validate the signature, only the certificate / public key (of Okta) is to be used.  What exception exactly do you get?

Comment: I am getting the following exception:
Incoming SAML message is invalid
org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: Validation of protocol message signature failed
 at org.opensaml.common.binding.security.SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.doEvaluate(SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.java:138) ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:na]
 

I have followed the steps from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/security.html but I am facing the same exception.

Comment: I haven't worked with spring-saml, so maybe you cfind the config much sooner. however - `signature failed` (assuming the response is signed and you have the Okta certificate imported in your keystore) may mean there's missing assignment between the certificate (alias) and the identity provider (entity id). definiton in the ExtendedMetadata such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045669/spring-security-saml-how-to-configure-client-auth

Comment: I'm facing exactly same issue, does anyone find the solution?